Coretime. How to check are there any coretime assigned to parachain
Followed this instruction.
https://forum.polkadot.network/t/parachain-consensus-updates-coretime-asynchronous-backing-scalability/4396/5
aura keys contains 2 accounts.
Run only one collator and registed para id and parathrhead id.
then on demand provider
but parachain does not produce any block..
How to check is there any core assigned to parachain?
